# Simultaneously animate the rotation and scale of a layer’s transform with different durations respectively

Tags: ios, core-animation

The problem below is that the duration given to the scale animation overwrites the rotation animation.

Is there any other way to simultaneously animate a CALayer's scale and rotation with different durations?

```
    // Animate arrowhead rotation
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.2)
    CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut))
    let arrowAngle = atan2(path.currentPoint.y - previousPoint.y,
                           path.currentPoint.x - previousPoint.x) + (.pi * 0.5)
    let rotationZ = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, arrowAngle, 0, 0, 1)
    arrowhead.transform = rotationZ
    CATransaction.commit()

    // Animate arrowhead scale
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.5)
    CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut))
    arrowhead.transform = CATransform3DConcat(rotationZ, arrowheadTransformScale)
    CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: @matt Is there any way to achieve animating a layer’s scale and rotation with different durations?

Comment: @matt I tried also to target specific aspects of the transform with this technique `arrowhead.setValue(arrowAngle, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.z")`

Comment: @matt Wouldn't that require the whole animation to use `kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is working:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let box = CALayer()
    box.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 300, width: 100, height: 100)
    box.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(box)

    let boxTransform = box.transform
    let currentAngle = atan2(boxTransform.m12, boxTransform.m11)

    let currentScale = getScale(for: box.affineTransform())

    let targetAngle: CGFloat = .pi / 3
    let targetScale: CGFloat = 2

    // Set layer properties to their target values before animating them.
    var affineTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: targetAngle)
    affineTransform = affineTransform.scaledBy(x: targetScale, y: targetScale)
    box.setAffineTransform(affineTransform)

    let rotate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotate.fromValue = currentAngle
    rotate.toValue = targetAngle
    rotate.duration = 2
    rotate.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

    let scaleUp = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    scaleUp.fromValue = currentScale
    scaleUp.toValue = targetScale
    scaleUp.duration = 4
    scaleUp.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

    let rotateAndScale = CAAnimationGroup()
    rotateAndScale.animations = [rotate, scaleUp]
    rotateAndScale.duration = 4

    // Setting key to "transform" overwrites the implicit animation created when setting the target values before the animation.
    box.add(rotateAndScale, forKey: "transform")
}

func getScale(for t: CGAffineTransform) -> CGFloat {
    return sqrt(t.a * t.a + t.c * t.c)
}
```

[image: Rotate and scale layer transform simultaneously]